# connect iOS/android project to firebase

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

When making one social media project on both Xcode and android studio platforms, how to connect both of them with firebase to make connection between the users of iPhone and android devices.

Comment: You seem to already have picked two technologies that allow you to do so. I'd recommend getting started with the codelabs for [Android developers](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/) and [iOS developers](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/). After taking those you should have a pretty good idea of how to get these two technologies talking with each other through Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone, but I found the answer in firebase.
The answer is to make a project with firebase and in the project create an iOS app and an android app in the same project, then both of them will use the same database.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the setup guide for both [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start) and [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start)

Once you've set them up on their respective IDE's and loaded them on your client they'll both connect to the same default databas thereby sharing the data.

Comment: If the answer works for you please don't forget to upvote / click the green tick next to the answer to say it's correct: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.